# Building Export Connector with ABBYY FlexiCapture?

Tags: c#, ocr, abbyy

I'm working on a project to capture and archive documents with ABBYY FC 12. 
there is a requirement to build an export connector to OpenText DMS.
This connector should have it's own interface to connect to the project and to map fields from ABBYY to their correspondent fields on OpenText DMS, and then save this configuration.

I went through ABBYY FC developer's guide and I found an example of using ABBYY FC web API and it worked well. But in this case the workflow will be un-attended and all stages will be executed through the API.

Can anyone help How to build an export connector for attended use?

I hope my issue is clear!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is to be implemented by script export. Just use "Custom export (script)" and write the code to get the values out of IDocument object and push it to your custom target.

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич thanks for your reply, I'm familiar with Custom Export inside document definition, but my question was : can we write an export connector outside of abbyy ex. VisualStudio with a UI so the user can use it to map ABBYY's fields with the back end system fields?

Comment: Indeed you can. Just code that for 1-2 months.
In the custom export script, you may connect an external DLL and call it to get rid of performing coding into ABBYY UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Abbyy FC Web API for the same. You will have to set up the Project in **Simple** workflow mode.

Once you have generated the `sessionId` and `batchId` and uploaded the documents to Abbyy using Web API, you can use the below code to recognize the document and get the `nextstage` and `taskId`.

```
 public enum eProcessingStageTypes
        {
            Scanning = 100,
            Rescanning = 150,
            Recognition = 200,
            UnattendedProcessing = 250,
            DocumentAssemblyCheck = 300,
            DataVerificationPreprocessing = 390,
            DataVerification = 400,
            DataVerificationPostprocessing = 410,
            VerificationPreprocessing = 490,
            Verification = 500,
            VerificationPostprocessing = 510,
            BatchIntegrityCheck = 600,
            ExportConfirmation = 700,
            ExportPrerecognitionforexporttoPDFsearchable = 780,
            Export = 800,
            Training = 850,
            Userrequestsprocessing = 950,
            Processed = 900,
            Exceptions = 1000,
            VerificationVerificationPreprocessing = 2001,
            VerificationVerificationPostprocessing = 2002,
            UnknownStage = -1,
            Failed = -2,
            NextStage = -3
        };

int projId = 0;
int roleId = 0;
int sessionId = 0;
int batchId = 0;
int roleType = 0;
int stationType = 0;
string guid = String.Empty;

//guid = Guid of Project on Abbyy FC

//roleType - https://help.abbyy.com/en-us/flexicapture/12/developer/troletype

//stationType - https://help.abbyy.com/en-us/flexicapture/12/developer/stationtypeenum

sessionId = fcSvcObj.OpenSession(roleType, stationType);
projectId = fcSvcObj.OpenProject(sessionId, guid);
batchId = fcSvcObj.AddNewBatch(sessionId, projectId, batch, 0);

fcSvcObj.ProcessBatch(sessionId, batchId);

Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
currBatch = new Batch();
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
var percentCompleted = 0;
double timeOut = 60;
double elapsedTime = 0.0;
stopWatch.Start();

while (percentCompleted < 100 && elapsedTime < timeOut && currBatch.StageExternalId < (int)eProcessingStageTypes.Recognition)
{
    percentCompleted = fcSvcObj.GetBatchPercentCompleted(batchId);
    currBatch = fcSvcObj.GetBatch(batchId);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds;
}

stopWatch.Stop();
stopWatch.Reset();


if (percentCompleted < 100 && elapsedTime > timeOut)
{
    throw new Exception("Timeout Error. Processing was not completed within maximum timeout provided.");
}


//Document has moved to Exceptions

if (currBatch.StageExternalId == (int)eProcessingStageTypes.Exceptions)
{
    throw new Exception("Document moved to exceptions");
}

//Document requires manual verification

if (currBatch.StageExternalId == (int)eProcessingStageTypes.Verification || currBatch.StageExternalId == (int)eProcessingStageTypes.DataVerification)
{
    TaskList tasks = fcSvcObj.GetAvailableTasks(sessionId, projId, 500, false);
    int taskId = tasks.Where(task => task.BatchId == batchId).FirstOrDefault().Id;

    // Generate Verification URL
    string verificationUrl = "http://servername/FlexiCapture12/Verification/Verify?projectId=<pid>&roleId=<rid>&taskId=<tid>&returnTo=DeadEnd&mode=mini";
    verificationUrl.Replace("<pid>",projectId).Replace("<rid>",roleId).Replace("<tid",taskId);

}

// Document is ready for export

if (currBatch.StageExternalId == (int)eProcessingStageTypes.Processed)
{
    //Code to Export Documents
}
```

Post that, you can navigate to the Web Verification Station on Abbyy to perform manual verification. The verification URL can be generated in the above code.

Post verification, the documents are ready for export and you can use the below code to perform export of documents.

You will need to save the `sessionId` and `batchId` from first part of processing to export the documents. You can use a new session as well, but ensure to close the session in first part of the process.

```
string outputFolderPath = "DestinationFolder";
bool isBatchOpen = fcSvcObj.OpenBatch(sessionId, batchId);

if (isBatchOpen)
{
    documents documents = fcSvcObj.GetDocuments(sessionId, batchId);

    if (documents == null) return;

    foreach (Document document in documents)
    {
        if (document.Id > 0)
        {
            fileNames fns = fcSvcObj.GetDocumentResultsList(sessionId, batchId, document.Id);

            if (fns != null)
            {
                foreach (string fn in fns)
                {

                    FCWebSvc.File file = fcSvcObj.LoadDocumentResult(sessionId, batchId, document.Id, fn);

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(outputFolderPath + Path.GetFileName(fn), file.Bytes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```